# Prevent timeout for UAC popup on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, uac

I was trying to download an update for a game on my new Windows 10 System. The update is quite huge and just a few minutes before it was supposed to end, I had to leave my keyboard a few minutes. Then when I got back, there was a poup asking if I authorized the game to make changes to my system, I was about to click "yes"/"Authorize"/ but then the popup disappeared causing the whole procedure to be considered failed and now I have to re download the whole thing again (I don't blame the game developers, here).

How can I avoid this to ever happening again without turning off UAC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UAC has a timeout of two minutes. If no acknowledgment is received within those
two minutes, the action fails silently (same as if you would have declined).

The are only three workarounds I can think of :

1. Start the program in Admin mode, so the UAC confirmation is done at the
   beginning.
2. Disable UAC for the duration
3. Use an auto-click product such as
   [ClickOff](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/clickoff.html)
   or
   [Dialog Devil](https://dair.com/ddevil/index.php).